# How to determine the final size of view before expand?

Tags: android, android-layout, height, expand

I have a LinearLayout containing a TextView. The initial height of LinearLayout is set to 20px where the content of TextView overflows its bounds. I want to animate LinearLayout to expand to wrap content (its Children height). How can I determine the final size of LinearLayout before expanding?

[image]

Currently I set Height of View to wrap_content for a moment and after measuring  the final height reset the height to 20 again! obviously this cause an unwanted blink before animation and should be replaced by a better solution.

```
//I hate these two lines
    view.getLayoutParams().height=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    view.requestLayout();
//End of hate!

view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
       view.getLayoutParams().height=20;
       view.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [.measure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure(int,%20int)) method for this:

```
view.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: measure takes MeasureSpec as a parameters, so MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT are not suitable here